# How to shorten certain substrings in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series of SKUs in a DataFrame: `[35641, 265689494123, 36492, 56526246546, 26412...]`.

The problem is that the long barcodes (like 56526246546) in the DataFrame need to be truncated at certain points. The length over 5 should trigger the deletion process, which truncates like [7:12] in a list.

I tried using the following code without any prevail:

```
if df.loc[len(df['SKU']) > 5]:
    df.loc[df['SKU'].df.slice(start=7,stop=12)]
```

I get following error messages:

```
  KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: True

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-cea7b4ca2640> in <module>
      1 #g[:] = (elem[:12] for elem in g)
----> 2 if df.loc[len(df['SKU']) > 5]:
      3     df.loc[df['SKU'].df.slice(start=7,stop=12)]

c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1498 
   1499             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1500             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1501 
   1502     def _is_scalar_access(self, key):

c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1911         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1912         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1913         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1914 
   1915 

c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    139             raise IndexingError('no slices here, handle elsewhere')
    140 
--> 141         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    142 
    143     def _get_loc(self, key, axis=None):

c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3583                                                       drop_level=drop_level)
   3584         else:
-> 3585             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3586 
   3587             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

c:\users\User\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: True
```

How do I fix this code?

P.S Some of the error messages seem to be popping up due to the fact that I've added the code BEFORE converting the dict into a DataFrame.

Comment: can you show an output sample?

Comment: Of course. It would be 35641, 49412, 46546, 26412 for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output you want, I think you can use:

```
df['SKU'] = df['SKU'].apply(lambda x: int(str(x)[6:11]) if len(str(x)) > 5 else x)
```

Output:

```
     SKU
0  35641
1  49412
2  36492
3  46546
4  26412
```

Comment: Just a small question, why does this code df.loc[df['SKU'] == 40767] not return anything after adding the code line?

Comment: SKU 40767 certainly existed beforehand and it worked.

Comment: I think it depends from the type

Comment: Oh that's correct, it's a string now. Silly mistake from my side. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
df.loc[:, 'SKU'] = df.loc[:, 'SKU'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[7:12] if len(x) > 5 else x)
```